# When does a player's turn end in the Now That's What I Call Music board game?

Tags: now-thats-what-i-call-music

Note, this question is about the [board game](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Board-Games/Paul-Lamond-6745-Entertainment-Thats/B073FVSH2T) not the similarly-themed card game or DVD-based games.

The rules state that when your turn begins, you roll the dice and take various actions depending on what you roll and what you then land on - for example, answer a question from a card, or act out a song title charades-style. All of the rules describing the actions say that if you fail (get the question wrong, no-one guesses your charade, etc.) then your turn ends. There are also some other cases where the rules explicitly state that your turn ends, for example if you roll the dice and land on a space with no symbol on it.

To me this implies that if you succeed (answer the question correctly, someone guesses your charade, etc.) then you should roll again and have another go still in your same turn. This would be the same ethos as eg Trivial Pursuit. However, nowhere in the rules does it explicitly say this and it seems like a pretty big omission if I am correct.

Is there a definitive answer to this? Do other players have house rules about it?

Edit: pics of the rules attached.[image]

Comment: If a player is able to continue to move after a success on a play and they are lucky with their rolls does that mean they could win the game on their first turn before anyone else can get a chance to roll? While I know that situation like that would be unlikely I always think it is a good idea to include worst case situations when trying to determine the meaning in rules.

Comment: @JoeW, technically yes, but it’s very unlikely as there are plenty of the “no symbol” spaces where your turn ends as soon as you land on it. Also your turn ends after following the instructions on the wildcard if you land on a pig symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Quick disclaimer I've never played this and struggled to find printed rules online.  My rules source here is a [YouTube unboxing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjEFTPJN1cQ) which showed both sides of the rules sheet.

from my screen cap of the rules the wording is:-

> If the active player answers the question correctly their piece remains where it is.  If they answer incorrectly they go back to where they started their turn.  This is the end of their turn.

If a player was to continue and take another turn this should and would be explicitly stated in the rules.  I personally would read that as "The player wither remains where they are, or moves back.  THEN (regardless of the result) their turn ends.

The other rules for Song Charades and Oldies follow a similar pattern of stating what happens for success and failure and then that turn passes on.  From reading this I don't think you can assume the players take successive turns in a Trivial Pursuit fashion. Just because it's the rule in another game does not mean it is here.  This to me is a case of 'If its not printed in the rules to take extra goes then it isn't the rule'

Comment: Thanks. I can sort of see that for the selection you quoted, but I have now added a picture of the rules to the post and you can see that if you roll a 5 or a 6, the rules are phrased as "If you win, you move forward two spaces. If not, you stay where you are and play passes to the next person." which is much more ambiguous....

Comment: Also, I do agree with you that if it is intended to mean "have another go if you get it right" then that really ought to be stated explicitly. I have asked the manufacturer for a definitive answer and will post again here if they get back to me.